# How to get the list of folders from a branch in perforce?

Tags: java, perforce

I'm using perforce api to read the list of folders in a branch in java.

I reached to a point which tells me to get Branch spec.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/IServer.html#getBranchSpec(java.lang.String)

---

Used the following code to implement `getDirectories()` method.

```
String serverUri = "p4java://<server-address>:1666?userName=username&password=password";
IServer server = ServerFactory.getServer(serverUri, null);
server.connect();

List<IFileSpec> inputList = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("//domain/code/branches/");
System.out.println("HelloPerforce.main() >> passed list >> " + inputList );

List<IFileSpec> outputList =  server.getDirectories(inputList , false, false, false);
System.out.println("HelloPerforce.main()  >> directory list >> " + outputList );
```

**Output:** The outputList is null.

**Expected output:** List of folder names inside `//domain/code/branches` directory.

Can someone please point me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is getDirectories().  A branch spec is a mapping between two branches (which are usually *but not necessarily* top-level depot paths).  Usually if you're talking about a single "branch" what you're talking about is a depot path, e.g. "//depot/main", rather than a branch spec.  To get the list of folders under the "main" branch you'd ask for the list of directories matching "//depot/main/*".

Comment: Thanks Sam. getDirectories actually lists all the 'matching' directories for passed-in file specifications. So if i pass "//depot/main" it lists me the exact same directory in perforce and not folders inside main directory. 

How can I get the list of directories inside that folder? Coudnt find any function for that.

Comment: As in my example, use "//depot/main/*".  The trailing "/*" is the part that will match the subdirectories.  :)